# ApplicationBarIconButton lookalike

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, button

Does anybody knows how to make a button look like an `ApplicationBarIconButton`? 
I want to place the button in a stackpanel on a page, not in an ApplicationBar.

The button must have the same effects, and must have a round circle around the icon image.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<Border CornerRadius="50" BorderThickness="4" Height="68" Width="68" BorderBrush="White">
     <Button Content="A" BorderThickness="0" Height="68" Width="68" Margin="-9,-4,-8,5" FontSize="36" Foreground="White"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: That solution is not ideal because it cannot use images and does not have an effect when touched

Answer (score 0):

You can [draw your own button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613598.aspx) template in Expression Blend (it's free for WP7 developers)

Use a `"{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundColor}"` as a color for your button.

Answer (score 0):

You may use http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio which allows you to create custom icons. I found them very useful. I hope it helps you too

Comment: Seems like a useful program but I'm not paying $500 for 1700 icons.

Answer (score 0):

The [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com) has a RoundButton component I've used many times for this purpose. Just specify the image, and it'll draw the border and adjust for the phone's theme just like the application bar.